# Where are HERE maps docs about layer attributes?

Tags: here-api

I am experimenting with HERE Maps API. I am requesting Platform Data Extension API and getting a valid response.

The thing is I would like to know what do the values I get mean exactly? For example I can request ADAS_ATTRIB_FC1, is there any documentation telling me what do the slope values, curvature values etc. mean? And for other layer attributes?

Please see an example response for ADAS_ATTRIB request below:

```
{
    "Rows": [{
            "LINK_ID": "52795003",
            "HPX": "88135200,3000,9200,4200,2400,900,800,1200",
            "HPY": "487947300,700,2400,1100,700,200,100,-100",
            "HPZ": "48073,-76,-236,-107,-61,-23,-20,-30",
            "SLOPES": "-1866,6,1,33,-26,-31,-26,3837",
            "HEADINGS": "70051,-2011,-2374,6159,7062,8114",
            "CURVATURES": "1182,-1182,0,-14170,-7255,-5046",
            "VERTICAL_FLAGS": "0,0,0,0,0,0",
            "REFNODE_LINKCURVHEADS": "19928834:2225:72335",
            "NREFNODE_LINKCURVHEADS": "708877367:-29444:101120",
            "BUA_ROAD": "1",
            "BUA_ROAD_VERIFIED": "Y"
        }
}
```

I haven't found anything like this in the online documentation (https://developer.here.com/documentation/platform-data/topics/layers-indexes-attributes.html) nor in the pdf documentation.

Since the HERE support doesn't reply at all, I am posting my question here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give it a try with [PLATFORM EXTENSION REST API](https://developer.here.com/documentation/platform-data/topics/example-layer.html) with GET request as following:

```
http://pde.cit.api.here.com/1/doc/layer.json?region=NA&release=LATEST&layer={name}&app_id={your_id}&app_code={your_code}
```

Try to learn more about [resources and indexes](https://developer.here.com/documentation/platform-data/topics/resources.html) in order to retrieve a response you are looking for.
For example to get the whole list of attributes and corresponding layers in EU you can request as follows:

```
http://pde.cit.api.here.com/1/doc/attributes.json?region=EU&release=LATEST&app_id={your_id}=&app_code={your_code}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I wanted. I guess I have missed it while clicking through the documentation.